# � rendered instead of `é` in dockerized java GUI application

Tags: linux, x11, docker, opensuse, java

Whenever I type the `é` character, or any letter with diacritics, the � glyph is rendered instead. The actual key sequence is <kbd>´</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>. The app seems to be AWT-based (from error messages, font rendering trick).

What works:

- Symbols like <kbd>£</kbd>,<kbd>¢</kbd>,<kbd>°</kbd>
- Pasting the `é` character
- Typing the `é` character inside another app, like Firefox

What doesn't work:

- Typing the `é` character
- The openjdk base image couldn't even launch the app

```
FROM registry.opensuse.org/opensuse/leap:latest

RUN zypper --non-interactive in java-1_8_0-openjdk curl unzip shadow fonts-config dejavu-fonts

ENV USER=user GROUP=users GID=100 UID=1000
RUN useradd -mr -u ${UID} -g ${GROUP} ${USER}

RUN curl -o /tmp/irpf.zip http://downloadirpf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/irpf/2020/irpf/arquivos/IRPF2020-2.0.zip && \
    unzip -d /opt /tmp/irpf.zip && \
    rm -f /tmp/irpf.zip

USER ${USER}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}

ENV LANG="pt_BR.UTF-8"
ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dswing.aatext=TRUE -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on'
ENV XAUTHORITY=/home/${USER}/.Xauthority

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/IRPF2020/irpf.jar"]
```